# How can i make multiple routes in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have this two routes

```
 Route::get('/{bank}', array('as' => 'id', 'uses' => 'BanksController@single'));
Route::get('/{city?}/{sort?}', 'BanksController@index');
```

When I type in http /alfa_bank I see the BanksController@single action
And When i type /new_york I see the same

How can I see BanksController@index action with condition than it will be first parametr in router

Answer (score 3):

With the banks and the cities sharing the same character set, you really can't differentiate between the two, and Laravel's routing doesn't allow you to fall through to another route from within another route.

It looks like the index route should all banks in a particular city (if a city is provided), so I'd suggest the following route definitions:

```
Route::get('/', 'BanksController@index');
Route::get('/{bank}', ['as' => 'id', 'uses' => 'BanksController@single']);
```

Within the index method, you can still look for a city and sort type as query parameters:

```
$city = $request->query('city');
$sort = $request->query('sort');
```

URLs to the index would look like this:

```
https://example.com/?city=new_york
https://example.com/?city=new_york&sort=asc
```